# Как отправить почту со своего домена

Tags: golang, email, smtp, imap, pop3

- Купил домен, условно `example.com`.
- Арендовал VDS на Ubuntu.
- Написал сайт
- Хочу, чтобы пользователи сайта могли получать письма от отправителя `test@example.com`

Занимаюсь вопросом не первую неделю, чёткости нет абсолютно никакой. Где-то написано, что нужно поднять почтовый сервер на VDS (например, `postfix`). Где-то написано, что нужно использовать сторониие почтовые серверы (например, яндекс). Сколько ни старался, с `postfix` ничего не отправляется даже встроенной утилитой `sendmail`, не говоря уже об отправке почты средствами языка программирования. Подключение к яндексу - тоже окутано тайной. Добавил миллион DNS записей, зарегистрировался в яндекс.коннекте, добавил туда домен, все проверки прошёл.

В общем - как отправить почту на любой почтовый адрес любым протоколом (smtp, imap, pop) со своего домена из языка программирования `Golang`?

Comment: по поводу провайдера, блокирующего внешние соединения на 25-й порт. проверить-то элементарно: `$ telnet mx.yandex.ru 25`, или `$ nc mx.yandex.ru 25`, или любым другим способом.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется отправлять через sendmail с консоли, то нужно sendmail'у подсказать, какой у Вас адрес отправителя. Есть классическая инструкция - https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Sendmail-Address-Rewrite-3.html. Если супер кратко - нужно настроить файл `/etc/mail/genericsdomain` (где вписать Ваш домен) и `/etc/mail/genericstable`, что бы sendmail знал, от какого имени слать письмо.

Теперь в го. Попробуйте такой код

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/smtp"
)

func main() {

  // Ваша почта и пароль
  from := "from@gmail.com" 
  password := "<Email Password>"

  // кому шлем письмо.
  to := []string{
    "sender@example.com",
  }

  // настройки smtp сервера.
  smtpHost := "smtp.gmail.com"
  smtpPort := "587"

  // Собственно само сообщение
  message := []byte("This is a test email message.")
  
  // логинимся на севере
  auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", from, password, smtpHost)
  
  // шлем письмо
  err := smtp.SendMail(smtpHost+":"+smtpPort, auth, from, to, message)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  fmt.Println("Письмо ушло!")
}
```

Comment: dial tcp 64.233.162.109:587: connect: connection timed out

Comment: естественно, что сервер желательно поднять. Но настройка почтового сервера это особое приключение

Comment: Но если Вы настроили PDD (почта для домена от Яндекса), то в качестве smtp сервера наверно нужно указывать адреса яндекса

Comment: буду пробовать, спасибо за помощь

Comment: поджкажите, пожалуйста, что в Go коде указывать в smtpHost, from и password, если я настроил (или только попытался настроить) postfix?

Comment: если настроили локально, то в качестве smtpHost наверно будет 127.0.0.1 (если почта прям с сайта отправляется) или просто айпи/домен Вашего сайта. from/password - создайте себе аккаунт на сервере.

Comment: Всё оказалось прощё. Хостинг провайдер блокировал исходящие соединения по 25ому порту, нужно было обратиться в поддержку, чтобы разблокировали. Проверял это ранее - находил информацию, что на этом хостинг провайдере порт не блокируется. Всё заработало